# Salesforce DX using Visual Studio Code Debugging Scratch Orgs

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforcedx, scratch-org, vs-code

Learning more about using Visual Studio Code and Salesforce DX

Latest video from salesforce.org apps team
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgvYKDqb6Ng

Anyone have any luck using the Apex Debug permission settings and being able to debug using Visual Studio Code in Scratch Orgs?